# FB.XFBML.parse() scrolls browser to last loaded comment/like in IE and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, facebook-social-plugins

This is about my canvas app when loaded in IE and firefox.

I am using pagination. Now suppose 1st page has a comment box, its loaded fine (dont know why?). Now, I request the next page using ajax. again by using FB.XFBML.parse() and this page also has some comment boxes. But this time the page scrolls down to the last loaded comment box.

I tried using both HTML5 and XFBML plugins.

Comment: show us ehat you have done. Paste some code!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue with fb js, which tries to parse XFBML and then move the focus to the current parsed element. check all.js for f.parse = (function () { ....

I know its not the most appropriate solution but try

```
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
```

on the callback of FB.XFBML.parse.

Comment: Hey Vinay, Thnx, but did this exactly yesterday . check out the app. It "dances" there. It goes down to the last rendered box/like and then jumps back up. But sometimes it doesnt come back, just stays there.